# Does angular2 support forEach loop? If, Yes! Then, why it prints all the Object with same value?

Tags: angular

Guys i'm trying to get server response object. And passing it into a new Array object which is shown in below code. But, the problem i'm getting here is when i tried to print those newly passed objects using forEach loop. It's displaying duplicated objects. How to overcome this problem guys.

```
  //This is the my newly created Object with following properties
  obj: Object = new Object({
                           value:"",
                           label:"",
                           percentage: "",
                           color:"",
                           highlight: "" });

  data: Array<Object> = []; // This is a array object to which i need to pass my newly created object with respective properties as shown above.

 // This is the code to get response object from server and pass those all response object into newly created object called "obj" using for-each in angular 2

this.trafficChartService.getChartDetails().subscribe(response =>{
  this.myRes = response.sectionPercentage;
  this.myRes.forEach(ele =>{
    let dashboardColors = this._baConfig.get().colors.dashboard; 
    this.obj.value = ele.value;
    this.obj.label = ele.label;
    this.obj.percentage = ele.percentage;
    this.obj.color = dashboardColors.gossip;
    this.obj.highlight = colorHelper.shade(dashboardColors.gossip, 15);
    this.data.push(this.obj);// Here's the problem
  });
  console.log(this.data); // ***
})

// Here's the snapshot of those object which i printed in *** above
```

[image: Object with repeated property value]

Comment: What is `[Object with repeated property value][1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  this.myRes.forEach(ele =>{
    let dashboardColors = this._baConfig.get().colors.dashboard; 
    // here you are re-using the same object instance every time
    this.obj.value = ele.value;
    this.obj.label = ele.label;
    this.obj.percentage = ele.percentage;
    this.obj.color = dashboardColors.gossip;
    this.obj.highlight = colorHelper.shade(dashboardColors.gossip, 15);
    // here the same object gets added every time
    this.data.push(this.obj);// Here's the problem
  });
  console.log(this.data); // ***
})
```

Because you're using the same object instance every turn, the result is an array with the same object added x times.

This should do what you want:

```
  this.myRes.forEach(ele =>{
    let dashboardColors = this._baConfig.get().colors.dashboard; 
    var obj = {};
    obj.value = ele.value;
    obj.label = ele.label;
    obj.percentage = ele.percentage;
    obj.color = dashboardColors.gossip;
    obj.highlight = colorHelper.shade(dashboardColors.gossip, 15);
    this.data.push(obj);// Here's the problem
  });
  console.log(this.data); // ***
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are changing the SAME object every time!

```
this.obj.value = ele.value; // <<<< this will override the pushed ones!!
this.obj.label = ele.label; // <<<< this will override the pushed ones!!
this.obj.percentage = ele.percentage; // <<<< this will override the pushed ones!!
this.obj.color = dashboardColors.gossip; // <<<< this will override the pushed ones!!
this.obj.highlight = colorHelper.shade(dashboardColors.gossip, 15); // <<<< this will override the pushed ones!!
this.data.push(this.obj);// Here's the problem
```

Should look like this:

```
this.obj = new Object({
                       value:"",
                       label:"",
                       percentage: "",
                       color:"",
                       highlight: "" });
this.obj.value = ele.value;
this.obj.label = ele.label;
this.obj.percentage = ele.percentage;ones!!
this.obj.color = dashboardColors.gossip;pushed ones!!
this.obj.highlight = colorHelper.shade(dashboardColors.gossip, 15);
this.data.push(this.obj);// Here's the problem
```